# Storage pool unavailable

Tags: zfs, storage, lxd

Hi I am trying to reinstall lxd because I messed up somewhere. Actually I tried to increase the zfs pool size, and closed the terminal abruptly. On restarting I created more problems, so I am trying to reinstall lxd.

In uninstalling lxd, I started deleting everything, but I am unable to delete the default storage pool (the one that I was trying to resize).

lxd storage list:

```
+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------+
|  NAME   | DRIVER |                   SOURCE                   | DESCRIPTION | USED BY |    STATE    |
+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| default | zfs    | /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/disks/default.img |             | 0       | UNAVAILABLE |
+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------+
```

and for lxd storage delete default:

> Error:
> Failed to remove directory "/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default":
> remove /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default:
> directory not empty

How to resolve this? I just want to delete the storage pool and install lxd afresh

Comment: In your output: `directory not empty`. See what is in that directory. Delete or preserve the contents. Then try again.